# Vi: how can I paste the last string of text that I entered when I was in insert mode?

Tags: vim, vi

How can I paste the last string of text that I entered when I was in insert mode? I think I've done this before on accident but I can't recall how.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the command you're looking for is simply `.` (period/full stop key). It's a normal mode command, so simply press the key in normal mode.

Comment: `.` in normal mode will repeat the last change. If you want to paste the last inserted text it can be found in the `.` register. e.g. `".p` In insert mode to insert the last inserted text use `<c-a>`

Comment: Sorry - but what is `<c-a>` because CTRL-a didn't work for me ...